# String replace in unicode is not working

Tags: java

I have get the below unicode string when executing the mysql query.

**\u30ad\u30e3\u30f3\u30bb\u30eb**

i have try to print the above string which has not properly changed to utf character.
So, i have try to replace "\" to "\".

> **str.replace("\\\\","\\");** //is not properly replaced

replace function is not work in my scenario.

How can i replace "\\" to "\" in my case.

sorry for my english !!

Any idea ?

Comment: `How can i replace "\" to "\"`. Come on!

Comment: @Eng.Fouad sorry.. "\\" to "\"

Comment: I don't think String.replace(…) is the right method to use here. Investigating.

Comment: try this .. String x = "\\u30ad\\u30e3\\u30f3\\u30bb\\u30eb"; x = x.replace("\\\\","\\"); println(x)

Answer (score 2):

String is immutable, you cannot change it once you create it. you need to assign the object that is returned from `replace()` method to a new String reference (or use the same reference):

```
str = str.replace("\\\\","\\");
```

Comment: String x = "\\u30ad\\u30e3\\u30f3\\u30bb\\u30eb";
x = x.replace("\\\\","\\");
print(x)

Comment: What do you need exactly? Why would you replace the "\" of "\u" special character?

Comment: i want to printing utf8 character(japanese) from above string

Comment: `System.out.println("\u30ad\u30e3\u30f3\u30bb\u30eb")` should print the Japanese characters without any problems. The problem could be in the console of the IDE you are using. Search for how to change the encoding of your IDE to support the Japanese characters.

Answer (score 1):

`String` literals like `"\u30ad\u30e3\u30f3\u30bb\u30eb"` are converted to unicode strings ("キャンセル") by java compiler. That means it works only on strings you put in your source file.

If you received string: `\u30ad\u30e3\u30f3\u30bb\u30eb` from a database, `\` is treated as any other character. If you remove it you will just get: `u30adu30e3u30f3u30bbu30eb`.

Instead you should write a method (or use existing one) which will find all escape sequences (`\u????`) in a `String` and convert them to real characters. See [here](http://www.koders.com/java/fidD26ED81BEBE41932C405904AD53AEE8459BB8509.aspx#L182) for example.